# C++ vector.push_back(string) seg faults after call to SQLGetData

Tags: c++, string, vector, char, odbc

http://www.easysoft.com/developer/languages/c/odbc_tutorial.html

I followed the above tutorial to query a MSSQL database using ODBC. I got it working and
now I am trying to wrap it inside a C++ class. I am seeing some unexpected behavior
in the following block of code.

```
while (SQL_SUCCEEDED(ret = SQLFetch(stmt)))
{
  vector<string> vRow;
  // loop through columns
  for (SQLUSMALLINT i = 1; i<= numCols; i++)
  {
    SQLINTEGER indicator;
    char buf[500];

    SQLRETURN data_ret;
    data_ret = SQLGetData(stmt, i, SQL_C_CHAR, buf, sizeof(buf), 
                          (SQLLEN*) &indicator); // <--- this call makes the first
                                                 // <--- entry of vRow disappear

    if (SQL_SUCCEEDED(data_ret))
    {
      if (indicator == SQL_NULL_DATA)
      {
        strcpy(buf, "NULL");
      }

      vRow.push_back(string(buf)); // <--- This line seg faults
    }
  }
}
```

Everything is fine on the first pass through the for loop, but on the second pass I get a segmentation fault when doing
    vRow.push_back(string(buf));

Stepping through with gdb I saw that the problem actually results from the second call to SQLGetData. After that line is executed I cannot access the first element of vRow.

```
(gdb) p vRow
$1 = std::vector of length 813681, capacity 813681 = {Cannot access memory at address 0x0
```

To me this seems like the first entry in vRows was a shallow copy of buf and the call to SQLGetData destroys the memory location, but everything I have read seems to indicate that a string does a deep copy.

I have played around with trying to "force" a deep copy of buf into a string before pushing it onto vRow, but all efforts exhibit the behavior.

I am compiling with g++ with these flags -std=c++0x -lboost_regex -lodbc

Can someone please help me figure out what is happening here?
Thank you in advance.

**UPDATE**
Changing the indicator variable from type SQLINTEGER to SQLLEN fixed the issue.

In the sqltypes.h header SQLLEN is a long, but SQLINTEGER is an int. So the call to SQLGetData was essentially casting a long into an int.

Comment: From the symptoms, it looks a buffer overrun when calling to `SQLGetData`. Because `vRow` and `buf` are in the stack, writing more bytes of size in `buf` will overwrite `vRow`, including the pointer to the allocated data. The question now is why that buffer overrun.

Comment: @Gonmator How can I see what is causing the overrun?

Comment: Wild guess: `SQLLEN` might be a larger type than `SQLINTEGER`, so the dodgy cast causes the call to `SQLGetData` to corrupt other variables on the stack. Why not declare `indicator` to be the correct type in the first place?

Comment: @MikeSeymour Nicely done! That fixed it. I was using SQLINTEGER because that is what they have in the tutorial, but they didn't have a cast. Mine would compile without it.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Right you are. Looking in the header sqltypes.h  SQLLEN  looks to be a long whereas SQLINTEGER is an int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the indicator variable from type SQLINTEGER to SQLLEN fixed the issue.

In the sqltypes.h header SQLLEN is a long, but SQLINTEGER is an int. So the call to SQLGetData was essentially casting a long into an int.

Thank you everyone for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you do memset of bug with '0', aftre declaring buf. That way it is ensured to have a backslash 0 at the end of the string, and will not cause seg fault. And make sure you pass sizeof(buf)-1, as last byte needs to be zero for C to treat like a string.

Comment: If I understand correctly, I added memset(buf, 0, sizeof(buf)-1); right after buf is declared. However, it did the same as before.

Comment: Following [SQLGetData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms715441%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) documentation: "Note that the driver counts the null-termination character when returning character data to *TargetValuePtr. *TargetValuePtr must therefore contain space for the null-termination character, or the driver will truncate the data."

Comment: ok, what is the value of indicator aftre the call has returned? try setting the buf[indicator] = '\0';, looks like the returned value is larger than the size of buf.

Comment: @Gonmator The data I receive is only 23 characters long, while buf has 500. I don't see any truncations happening. Am I missing something?

Comment: @user2505258: I was meaning you don´t need specify `sizeof(buf)-1`, since the null character is counted by the function. `sizeof(buf)` is OK.

Comment: @GangadharHeralgi Thanks, but buf[indicator] = '\0' make no change.

Comment: @GangadharHeralgi On the first pass indicator is 4. On the second pass indicator is 23.

Comment: The key is to get the buf null terminated, when you are doing string(buf), the constructor of string is not able to find the end of the buf, that is why it is causing the seg fault. You need to identify in which scenario the buf is remaining without being null terminated and add null termination for that scenario withing the size of buf, the null termination is must